# Use of differenct view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

i'm curious about what's the best way to plan the controllers for my app.

i want my main screen to have 3 button.
1) should open a nav controller with details view
2) should open a controller with other buttons that lead to others controllers
3) should open a tab bar with 2 pages ( or eventually use a switch to change page instead of the tab bar)

this is the schema of what i want
http://i59.tinypic.com/2rrvrd4.png

Is it a correct schema or i should use my controllers differently? will apple reject an apple with such schema?

thanks

Comment: It seems to me like it might be better to use a tab bar controller as the "main" controller with 4 tabs. But there's nothing wrong with yours.

Comment: How will the user get back to the first scene with three buttons?

Comment: i would prefer buttons so i can use nice graphics for a better UX, bug i'm glad you find mine ok ^^ thanks
@taimour i'll have a sort of "home" button

Comment: any other open questions? :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Fogmeister pointed out in the comments, going for a `UITabBarController` as the main interface for your app actually seems to be a more appropriate solution here.

However, you can go with the interface that you described, but then you should keep in mind that with your current setup, you are not only using `UINavigationController` in the first case, but your whole navigation system is still built upon `UINavigationController` in the following way:

Your app has *one* instance of `UINavigationController`.
Your initial `UIViewController` (the one with the three buttons), is the `rootViewController` of your `UINavigationController`.
You can navigate to the other view controllers using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController]` (or `performSegue` if you prefer using *Storyboards*).
In the case of your third view controller, you are pushing a `UITabBarController` onto the navigation controller's view controller stack, this `UITabBarController` needs to be initialized with the two view controllers that it is going to display before it gets pushed onto the stack.